# Context Initialization Failed - Injection of Autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, ear

I'm deploying an EAR on `IBM WAS 8.5`
I had no issues while building with Maven, nor while deploying on WAS.

But when trying to access the application, I'm getting an exception.

When I dug up the logs, I see the below trace and leaves me to no clue.

I have no clue, what's going wrong.
I checked if there are any dependency conflicts, they were none.

```
[5/18/17 10:57:47:392 EDT] 0000022c SystemOut     O 2017-05-18 10:57:47 ERROR DispatcherServlet:492 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dealerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.service.DealerService com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.controllers.DealerController.dealerService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dealerService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.dao.DealerDao com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.service.impl.DealerServiceImpl.dealerDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dealerDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.dao.impl.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/nseaiws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.service.DealerService com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.controllers.DealerController.dealerService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dealerService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.dao.DealerDao com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.service.impl.DealerServiceImpl.dealerDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dealerDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mbusa.nseai.services.dealer.dao.impl.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/nseaiws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 39 more
```

Please guide me.

**POM.XML:**

```
    <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
    <version.was>8.5</version.was>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ProjectRepo</id>
        <name>ProjectRepo</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring JDBC Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mbusa</groupId>
        <artifactId>mefeai</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Caching -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Caching -->
    <!--  Hibernate -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--  Hibernate -->
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mbusa.nseai</groupId>
        <artifactId>NSEAIMS</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Maven_Custom_Lib\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

<finalName>nseaiws</finalName>
<!--  Filter configuration start -->
<filters>
   <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/config-${env}.properties</filter>
  </filters>
    <resources>
     <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>


    </resources>

  <!--  Filter configuration end -->


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <webResources>
                         <resource>
                           <filtering>true</filtering>
                           <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                           <includes>
                             <include>**/*.xml</include>
                             <!-- include any other file types you want to filter -->
                           </includes>
                         </resource>
                       </webResources>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: post your `/WEB-INF/nseaiws-servlet.xml`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 It's not letting me post 2 blocks of code as i have reputation less than 10 :(

Comment: at least post the definition of bean `sessionFactory`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I added the servlet.xml. Please take a look.

Comment: you have pasted `servlet.xml` or `nseaiws-servlet.xml`, please post the second one.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 That's what it is. I just didn't name it nseaiws-servlet.xml

Comment: you are loading the config file itself again with `<import resource="classpath*:nseaims-context.xml"/>`?

Comment: @Jaiwo99  I added the pom.xml please take a look.. and let me know what to change .. Please

Answer (score 0):

The log says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index`, seems you have `JPA 2.0` on your classpath, assuming you are using Hibernate 4.3+, please make sure you have `JPA 2.1` on classpath, which should solve your problem.

add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the pom and help me out.

Comment: Trying.. will let u know

Comment: @user7391890 then exclude the old dependency

Comment: Can you please point out from the Pom.xml on which to include and which one to exclude please...

Comment: @user7391890 mvn dependency:tree